# Firebase Authentication: Authentication failed no matter what I'm trying Email and password

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

so I'm trying to set up firebase Authentication in my application for my firebase storage. But no matter what I'm trying it seems to just give me an authentication failed. I'm going off the tutorial inside of android studio's firebase extension. But it doesn't seem to work, I have all the dependencies in right and everything seems normal, but if I try to make an account or sign in with one made on the console it just gives me a failed authentication. I'll post the code I used below, I really hope someone can help me here because I have no idea whats going on. Thanks very much.

This is the code for the activity.

```
package com.example.alexwong.dungeonanddragonhelper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class AuthenticationActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "EmailPassword";

    private TextView mStatusTextView;
    private TextView mDetailTextView;
    private EditText mEmailField;
    private EditText mPasswordField;

    // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication);

        // Views
        mStatusTextView = findViewById(R.id.status);
        mDetailTextView = findViewById(R.id.detail);
        mEmailField = findViewById(R.id.field_email);
        mPasswordField = findViewById(R.id.field_password);

        // Buttons
        findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.email_create_account_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.verify_email_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        // [START initialize_auth]
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [END initialize_auth]
    }

    // [START on_start_check_user]
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);
    }
    // [END on_start_check_user]

    private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createAccount:" + email);
        if (!validateForm()) {
            return;
        }

        showProgressDialog();

        // [START create_user_with_email]
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(AuthenticationActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
        // [END create_user_with_email]
    }

    private void signIn(String email, String password) {
        Log.d(TAG, "signIn:" + email);
        if (!validateForm()) {
            return;
        }

        showProgressDialog();

        // [START sign_in_with_email]
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(AuthenticationActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.auth_failed);
                        }
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
        // [END sign_in_with_email]
    }

    private void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
        updateUI(null);
    }

    private void sendEmailVerification() {
        // Disable button
        findViewById(R.id.verify_email_button).setEnabled(false);

        // Send verification email
        // [START send_email_verification]
        final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        user.sendEmailVerification()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        // Re-enable button
                        findViewById(R.id.verify_email_button).setEnabled(true);

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(AuthenticationActivity.this,
                                    "Verification email sent to " + user.getEmail(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "sendEmailVerification", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(AuthenticationActivity.this,
                                    "Failed to send verification email.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
        // [END send_email_verification]
    }

    private boolean validateForm() {
        boolean valid = true;

        String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmailField.setError("Required.");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            mEmailField.setError(null);
        }

        String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            mPasswordField.setError("Required.");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            mPasswordField.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        if (user != null) {
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.emailpassword_status_fmt,
                    user.getEmail(), user.isEmailVerified()));
            mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));

            findViewById(R.id.email_password_buttons).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.email_password_fields).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.signed_in_buttons).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            findViewById(R.id.verify_email_button).setEnabled(!user.isEmailVerified());
        } else {
            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);
            mDetailTextView.setText(null);

            findViewById(R.id.email_password_buttons).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.email_password_fields).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.signed_in_buttons).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.email_create_account_button) {
            createAccount(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
        } else if (i == R.id.email_sign_in_button) {
            signIn(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
        } else if (i == R.id.sign_out_button) {
            signOut();
        } else if (i == R.id.verify_email_button) {
            sendEmailVerification();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the xml, not sure if its needed but I'll put it here incase.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/parchment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/emailpassword_title_text"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTitleText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            style="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail"
            android:text="@string/signed_out" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            style="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail"
            tools:text="Firebase User ID: 123456789abc" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_password_fields"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/field_email"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/field_password"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_password_buttons"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/email_password_fields"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/sign_in"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_create_account_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/create_account"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/signed_in_buttons"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:weightSum="2.0">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="@string/sign_out"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/verify_email_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="@string/verify_email"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you have enabled authentication with email/psw in the console?

Comment: @Dambakk Yep, absolutely positive I have.

Answer (score 0):

Could you also show the logcat for when Sign in fails? I need to see the exception that you are getting.
*I can't comment on the question because I don't have 50 reputation yet.*